# How application 's work is distributed on to worker nodes in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, worker

I have an application that reads a file do some calculation and generates output file in driver machine. Now when i run it with a slave on machine A it takes 6 mins . If i add one more slave on machine B to same cluster and run driver program it takes 13 mins ( with few no route found to host machine B ) . I believe it is due to network latency delay . Least time with 2 workers is always higher than 1 worker .   Then too some how i think , that application's work is not executing in distributed manner. Both the slaves are doing whole work independently. Both slaves read  input file as a whole and create RDD and send to driver for output. I am wondering then where is the distributed computing for which Apache Spark is known for ? 
I have a small word count program , that only does computation and no File I/O is involved  , if i run that with a huge file with multiple worker nodes  , I see execution time decreases with the addition of a worker . 
I want to know is each worker reads full file and create RDD and no distributed work is happening in the program ?

Thanks much .

--edit PFA the screen shot with various worker nodes . Corresponding colored rectangle shows the execution output. I am wondering why addition of more workers delays the execution time . I see No route to host exception at time in log  , but then why it doesn't come when i remove any one of the  worker . Any pointers ?  -- Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I do not have shared file system like HDFS . so i have copied input file to each worker node at a given location . alternatively if i give file:/tmp/loan.txt then master copies the file to both the worker's working dir.

Comment: For text file, the executors will only read the part of the files that's assigned to it by the driver. They will not read the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took a small dataset, put it on a file system that isn't distributed and ran that through an engine designed designed to run with hundreds of node - what can go wrong?

coordinating processes over a lot of computers requires a lot of coordination, sending data back and forth, serializing and deserializing etc. If you can't run a solution any other way the overhead is acceptable but if you run it on something small you are more affected by the overhead than the time that takes to solve the problem

Comment: Hi Arnon, thanks for replying . It is not small dataset . in fact input file has 1.5 m recs .  but what i am not clear at is  are both the workers reading input file fully ? i was under impression that master distributes data among workers that in turn gets computed and returned back . If both workers are reading file fully , how can enforce workers to read file in distributed way ?

Comment: will sc.textFile(" file" , 4) help ? I am using sc.textFile("file") , is that why both worker nodes are reading full file ?

Comment: Well, i tried doing partitioning to 4 sc.textFile("file",4) but that didnt help improve the performance  when i add workers.

Comment: With 7 workers, wouldn't you want to split into 7 partions to utilize them all? 
What was your solution to this?